# Backbone.js Events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events

I have a view I am able to load.  However the events do not fire.  Here is the view:

```
MapModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
events: {
    'click #closeMapModal': 'closeModal',
    'click #modal_streetview': 'renderStreet'
},
initialize: function(){
    this.el = $('.modal_box');
    this.template = _.template($('#map-modal-template').html());
    _.bindAll(this, 'renderMap', 'renderPin');
},

render: function(){
    $(this.el).show().append(this.template({
        model: this.model
    }));
    this.renderMap();
    this.renderPin();
},
renderMap: function(){
    this.thisLat = _this.model.get('lat');
    this.thisLng = _this.model.get('lng');
    this.modalMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('modalMap'), {
        zoom : 12,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(this.thisLat, this.thisLng), // VANCOUVER
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
},
renderPin: function(){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(this.thisLat, this.thisLng),
        map : this.modalMap,
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon : '/img/lazy-pin.png'
    });        
},
renderStreet: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.modalMap.getStreetView().setPosition(this.modalMap.center);
    this.modalMap.getStreetView().setVisible(true);
},
closeModal: function(e){
    alert('hello');
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.el).hide().find('div').remove();
}
```

})

I removed one of the event functions because it wasn't important.  Anyways, this view is initialized in my router:

```
    this.mapModalView = new MapModalView();
```

And I have a tooltip view, which has an event inside of it, that calls the render function from ModalMapView.  Here is that View:

```
ToolTipView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template($('#toolTip').html());
    this.mapTemplate = _.template($('#map-modal-template').html());
    this.model.bind('change:tooltip', this.toggleTooltip, this);
    return this;
},

events: {
    'mouseenter': 'toolTipOn',
    'mouseleave': 'toolTipOff',
    'click #show-restaurant-map': 'mapModal'
},

mapModal: function(){
    router.mapModalView.render(this.model);
},

render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        model: this.model
    }));
    this.delegateEvents();
    return this;

}
```

});

I removed the functions that I didnt think would be important again above.

Also, here is my template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="map-modal-template">
<div id="map_modal">
    <button title="Close" id="closeMapModal" class="right">Close</button>
    <h3>Restaurant Map &amp; Access Information</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="Map View" id="modal_mapview">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Street View" id="modal_streetview">Street View</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Parking &amp; Access Info" id="modal_parking">Parking &amp; Access Info</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="modalMap"></div>
</div>
</script>
```

and of course, my HTML markup on the page I am working on:

```
<div class="modal_box"></div>
```

Comment: FYI, I have been using backbone for about 2 months now so I am still new at this.

Comment: I should have mentioned, closeMapModal is the event that isnt firing (hence the alert)

Comment: I should also add, it appears these elements are not having the events assigned to them... the question is, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).show().append(this.template({
        model: this.model
    }));
    this.renderMap();
    this.renderPin();
    this.delegateEvents();
},
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any `_this` defined anywhere so I would expect everything to stop running as soon as you call `renderMap` and that would prevent your events from doing anything.

I do see this:

```
MapModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //...
    _this: this,
```

but that doesn't create a `_this` in the object's scope, that just creates a default `this._this` for your view instances; furthermore, when MapModalView is being built, `this` will probably be `window` so all you're doing is giving each MapModalView an reference to `window` in `this._this`.

I think all your `_this` references should be `this` and perhaps you want to add:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'renderMap, 'renderPin');
```

to MapModalView's `initialize` method to make sure those two always have the right `this` when you call them.

---

And now for the underlying problem now that we have mostly functional code.

Backbone views have an [`el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el):

> All views have a DOM element at all times (the el property), whether they've already been inserted into the page or not.

and they have an [`$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el):

> A cached jQuery (or Zepto) object for the view's element.

The [`delegateEvents`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents) method operators on `this.$el`. You don't specify an `el` (or `id`, `tagName`, ...) as part of your view's definition so Backbone initializes your `el` to an empty `<div>` and then initializes `this.$el = $(this.el)`. Your constructor changes `this.el`:

```
this.el = $('.modal_box');
```

but you don't do anything with `this.$el` so it still refers to the empty `<div>`. Remember that `delegateEvents` uses `this.$el` and that's not pointing at anything useful so your events don't get bound to anything in the DOM.

If you insist on setting `this.el` inside your `initialize`, then you'll have to set `this.$el` as well:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.el  = '.modal_box';
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    //...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/D996h/

Or you could use [`setElement()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) to set `el` and `$el` for you.

The usual approach is to set `el` as part of the view's definition:

```
MapModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.modal_box',
    //...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NasSN/

Or you can pass the `el` to the view when you instantiate it:

```
m = new MapModalView({el: '.modal_box'});
m.render();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9rsdC/

Comment: _this was doing its job, but i did change everything to your way, i will update my code, however this doesn't fix the event problem